# Sorting inside nested object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I am JS beginner and trying to sort a nested object i.e. PARTS in ascending order based on key value pairs of SUFFIX as shown:

```
Object: {
ID: 65,
MAIN: {ID: "GR", VALUE: 45},
PARTS:{
       0:{CODE: "GR3", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 3, YEAR: 3},
       1:{CODE: "GR4", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 4, YEAR: 2},
       2:{CODE: "GR1", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 1, YEAR: 5},
       3:{CODE: "GR2", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 2, YEAR: 4}
}
}
```

Expected output:

```
Object: {
ID: 65,
MAIN: {ID: "GR", VALUE: 45},
PARTS:{
       0:{CODE: "GR1", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 1, YEAR: 5},
       1:{CODE: "GR2", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 2, YEAR: 4},
       2:{CODE: "GR3", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 3, YEAR: 3},
       3:{CODE: "GR4", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 4, YEAR: 2}
}
}
```

Any suggestions how can I get the desired output.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have an object with `0...n` numerical keys. Why not use an array? Also, it looks like the `CODE:` key is the same even after sorting. Can you clarify? Lastly, I recommend taking a stab at it and sharing your code attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `values` to get PARTS and sort, after that use `assign` to convert array to object.

```
let obj = {
ID: 65,
MAIN: {ID: "GR", VALUE: 45},
PARTS:{
       0:{CODE: "GR3", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 3, YEAR: 3},
       1:{CODE: "GR4", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 4, YEAR: 2},
       2:{CODE: "GR1", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 1, YEAR: 5},
       3:{CODE: "GR2", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 2, YEAR: 4}
}
}

let res = Object.values(obj.PARTS).sort((a,b) => a.SUFFIX - b.SUFFIX);

obj.PARTS = Object.assign({}, res);

console.log(obj)
```

```js
let obj = {
ID: 65,
MAIN: {ID: "GR", VALUE: 45},
PARTS:{
       0:{CODE: "GR3", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 3, YEAR: 3},
       1:{CODE: "GR4", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 4, YEAR: 2},
       2:{CODE: "GR1", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 1, YEAR: 5},
       3:{CODE: "GR2", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 2, YEAR: 4}
}
}

let res = Object.values(obj.PARTS).sort((a,b) => a.SUFFIX - b.SUFFIX);

obj.PARTS = Object.assign({}, res);

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {
ID: 65,
MAIN: {ID: "GR", VALUE: 45},
PARTS:{
       0:{CODE: "GR3", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 3, YEAR: 3},
       1:{CODE: "GR4", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 4, YEAR: 2},
       2:{CODE: "GR1", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 1, YEAR: 5},
       3:{CODE: "GR2", PREFIX: "GR", SUFFIX: 2, YEAR: 4}
    }
};
var sortable = [];
for (let p in obj.PARTS) {
    sortable.push(obj.PARTS[p]);
}
obj.PARTS = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.SUFFIX > b.SUFFIX;
});
```

now your obj has the nested part sorted ascending based on SUFFIX